# Getting a folder into GitHub having tried before incorrectly

Tags: git, powershell, github, repository

[image: recent local git commands with responses]

I have been trying to create my first repository through the Powershell but I am having problems.

My first problem is that "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits." I am have tried to create repository this way before, with the same name, but I cannot understand properly what the stage is here and how it affects me. Originally I had tried to follow the online tutorials but I have obviously caused some mess.

I then tried to push local commits to the repository and this failed.

I then found online that I may not have git, so I tried the command art-get install git, which did not work. I would find it strange because that I did not have git because I had downloaded git for desktop and git powershell.

I am now stuck with how to push the local repository into a new github repository.

**UPDATE**:

After creating the github repository per the answer below, I'm still unable to push:

[image]

Comment: You ran `git` commands correctly. So you have git. You *don't* have `apt-get` as that's a debian/ubuntu command not a Windows one. The real error is what `git push` reports and the given answer covers that. (Aside: Why did you run `git init` there? What were you expecting that to do?)

Comment: Where did you clone this repository from? What URL?

Comment: @EtanReisner I ran git init because it is in all git tutorials on uploading projects to GitHub. I thought you had to run it to initialise the repository

Comment: Tutorials on how to create a new repository locally start with `git init`, yes. Tutorials on cloning an existing repository to contribute to them should not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question subject is

> Getting a folder into github having tried before incorrectly

I assume the issue you're asking about is the `git push` which states:

```
remote: Repository not fonud.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/gf1721/Phorch.git/' not found
```

This suggests that you haven't actually created the repository on Github yet (and when I look I certainly don't see a public repository there). You need to [create a new github repository](https://github.com/new) before you can push to it (github won't automatically create the repository on `push`).

If you decide to initialize the repository with a `LICENSE` or `README` then you can't just `git push` into the newly created repository (you'll get a `rejected` error suggesting you do a `git fetch`). If you want this new file then you need to do `git pull` to merge the file locally, and then `git push` to get all your code up into github.

Comment: The repository exists and has an upstream so it came from somewhere. Which means the config got edited or corrupted at some point or something. The OP may need to create a new repo but I think it more likely that the config would just need fixing.

Comment: `The repository exists and has an upstream so it came from somewhere. Which means the config got edited or corrupted at some point or something.` That's not necessarily true, and given the fact that the `git push` doesn't specify a remote suggests it's not true. It looks, to me, like he read something about setting the remote, but never created the remote.

Comment: `git status` reports that he is ahead of `origin/master`. That means it *has* an `origin/master`. I suppose that could be a local branch with that name if things were really wrong but then the `push` would work and not look at the `github` URL though.

Comment: Hm. Fair point. I think this situation could happen if he simply changed the `origin` path, rather than adding a new remote. As is: I'm still pretty sure the solution (assuming the push path is where he actually wants to push) is to create the repo in github.

Comment: Right. If that's the URL the OP wants to push to and if there isn't a repo there (private or whatever) then the OP needs to create it. But we'll need to wait for the OP to chime in to know.

Comment: @EtanReisner I kept setting the repository and then deleting it because I have had problems with the desktop app. I have now set up the repo and will now try the commands again

Comment: @Guildencrantz See the above

Comment: @Jurassic I see the remote repository now, so what's the new error? Since you initialized the repository I imagine you're getting an error that you can't push now (if that's the case you could overwrite the initialized repository with `git push -f`, you'd just have to recreate the `LICENSE` file).

Comment: @Guildencrantz Ive got a new error which I have put in the question

Comment: @Jurassic, yup, that's what I was referring to in my last comment. You either need to `git pull` and merge in the `LICENCSE` file you initiated the github repository with, or you need to just `git push -f` to blow the `LICENSE` away with exactly what's in your local repository.

Comment: @Guildencrantz after git pull what should I do, I cant see any of the files on the website?

Comment: @Jurassic `git pull` only updates your local copy. After you merge you still need to `git push` to get it on github.